# Rails uploading to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two differnt buckets in the same Amazon S3 account. I can upload fine to one but not the other.

**pictures.rb**

```
def self.set_s3_direct_post
  return S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')
end
```

**aws.rb**

```
S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['S3_FIRST_BUCKET'])
```

Trying to change bucket (with `S3_SECOND_BUCKET` instead of `S3_FIRST_BUCKET`) results in a failed upload. I notice that the url for a failed upload is in the form:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/%E2%80%9Csecond_bucket%E2%80%9D
```

but a successful upload looks like:

```
https://first_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
```

How do I control this??

Comment: Looks like you have double (smart) quotes surrounding the second bucket name. Can you remove them?

Comment: You were absolutely on the money, see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable. I edited my ~/.profile file in TextEdit. The addition of the line:

```
export S3_SECOND_BUCKET="second_bucket"
```

put slightly curly double-quotes around `second_bucket`. Turns out these double-quotes are different to the ones Sublime Text 2 uses, which are straight (like above). The TextEdit versions weren't being recognised as quotes. Cheers TextEdit, you t**t.

Comment: Uncheck 'Smart Quotes' via Edit | Substitutions?